# path to images in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a program of a simple media player and in this program there is a mute function in the toolbar, but I want to to change the picture when it is clicked, I already have the pictures of the icons on my computer but how do I create a path to them to display them in a code like this:

```
void videoWidget::on_action_Sound_triggered()
{
    if (meinPlayer->isMuted() == true){
        meinPlayer->setMuted(false);
     ui->action_Sound->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/mute.png"));

    }
    else
    {
        meinPlayer->setMuted(true);
     ui->action_Sound->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/mute.png"));
    }
```

if I choose the path written in the properties of the image it gives me an error "Unclaimed breakpoint"

Comment: Are the images in any .qrc of your project? if not then you will have to use the fullpath of the image instead of ":/"

Comment: no they are in a different file on my pc , how do i create that fullpath @eyllanesc

Comment: What is the folder where your image is?

Comment: this is the location to the picture i want :

Comment: C:\Users\Hassan Moussa\Desktop\mohamad\uni\open_icon_library-standard-0.11\open_icon_library-standard\icons\ico\16x16 @eyllanesc